# Regular Expressions for file name matching

Tags: regex, bash

In Bash, how does one match a regular expression with multiple criteria against a file name?
For example, I'd like to match against all the files with .txt or .log endings.

I know how to match one type of criteria:

```
for file in *.log
do
        echo "${file}"
done
```

What's the syntax for a logical or to match two or more types of criteria?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do it the same way you'd invoke `ls`. You can specify multiple wildcards one after the other:

```
for file in *.log *.txt
```

Comment: Mostly works, but the only weird thing is that when I've no .txt files, ".txt" gets echo'ed.

Comment: @Mike you need to set the nullglob shell option using the shopt builting to avoid this

Answer (score 24):

Bash does not support regular expressions per se when globbing (filename matching). Its globbing syntax, however, can be quite versatile. For example:

```
for i in A*B.{log,txt,r[a-z][0-9],c*} Z[0-5].c; do
...
done
```

will apply the loop contents on all files that start with A and end in a B, then a dot and any of the following extensions:

- log
- txt
- r followed by a lowercase letter followed by a single digit
- c followed by pretty much anything

It will also apply the loop commands to an file starting with Z, followed by a digit in the 0-5 range and then by the .c extension.

If you really want/need to, you can enable extended globbing with the shopt builtin:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

which then allows significantly more features while matching filenames, such as sub-patterns etc.

See the Bash manual for more information on supported expressions:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching

EDIT:

If an expression does not match a filename, bash by default will substitute the expression itself (e.g. it will echo *.txt) rather than an empty string. You can change this behaviour by setting the nullglob shell option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This will replace a *.txt that has no matching files with an empty string.

EDIT 2:

I suggest that you also check out the `shopt` builtin and its options, since quite a few of them affect filename pattern matching, as well as other aspects of the the shell:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin

Answer (score 9):

```
for file in *.{log,txt} ..
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in $(find . -regex ".*\.log")
do 
  echo $f
end
```

Comment: The regex is matched against the full path including directories.

Comment: To not recurse into subdirectories use`-maxdepth 1` before `-regex ` (or after but with a warning).

Answer (score 4):

You simply add the other conditions to the end:

```
for VARIABLE in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    command1
    command2
    commandN
done
```

So in your case:

```
for file in *.log *.txt
do
        echo "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *.+(log|txt)
```

which could be easily extended to more alternatives:

```
for file in *.+(log|txt|mp3|gif|foo)
```